# Laravel with() eager loading returning empty data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I have a one-to-many relationship in my model. Basically a `Category` and a `Product`. A product can only have one category but a category can have many products. The code below works:

```
return Category::select('id', 'name')->whereIn('id', $categories)->with('products')->get();
```

It returns with a product key and within that the product columns in the database, but when I use eager loading it just returns an empty set:

```
return Category::select('id', 'name')->whereIn('id', $categories)->with(['products' => function($query){
            $query->limit(5);
        }])->get();
```

I've also tried adding the return keyword like this `return $query->limit(5);` but still no luck.

I have also tried specifying columns like this:

```
return Category::select('id', 'name')->whereIn('id', $categories)->with('products:id,name')->get();
```

But it still returns an empty dataset.

Since I'm building an API, this is what the JSON data looks like:

```
[
     {
        "id": 161,
        "name": "Health & Personal Care",
        "products": []
    },
    {
        "id": 256,
        "name": "Makeup & Fragrances",
        "products": []
    },
]
```

My table structure:

```
categories (there's no product_id column, since it's one to many)
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|    |      |
+----+------+
|    |      |
+----+------+
|    |      |
+----+------+

product
+----+------+-------+-------------+
| id | name | price | category_id |
+----+------+-------+-------------+
|    |      |       |             |
+----+------+-------+-------------+
|    |      |       |             |
+----+------+-------+-------------+
|    |      |       |             |
+----+------+-------+-------------+
```

My category model is declared like this:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

and the product model is:

```
public function category()
{
     return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked whether the definition of the relationship is correct

Comment: @rubys I'll add in my tables above

Comment: just try simple query without select specific column Category::whereIn('id', $categories)->with('products')->get();

Comment: @BhargavRangani but I want to select columns and only show 5 items per category.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to limit the loaded relation, not the query, you can do this using  [eloquent-eager-limit](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit)

install it:

```
composer require staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit:"^1.0"
```

then in Category Model:

```
class Category extends Model
{
use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
.....
public function products()
{
return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'product_id');
}

public function lastFiveProducts()
{
return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'product_id')
->latest()->limit(5);
}
    }
```

and in Product:

```
class Product extends Model
{
use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
......
}
```

now this query will get the expected results:

```
return Category::select('id', 'name')->whereIn('id', $categories)->with(['products' => function($query){
            $query->limit(5);
        }])->get();
```

or using the new relation:

```
  return Category::select('id', 'name')->whereIn('id', $categories)->with(['lastFiveProducts'])->get();
```

also note when you use `->with('products:id,name')` loading a relation with specific columns, you always should load the foreing key `->with('products:id,name,category_id')`